# How to simulate JQuery's find-last method with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do this project 100% Javascript, without any JQuery.

I have a table of ten columns that I want to add a new row when the user "Tabbs out" of the select box (class selectprod) of the last row of the table, regardless of how big or small it grows or shrinks to be. I don't want every select.selectprod to have this keydown attribute, just the select.selectprod of the last row of the dynamic table.

The problem is, when I add the addEventListener (the only way I can think to do this, which is probably wrong) to the last row and later add a new row, I have to removeEventListener from the previous row and add it to the new last row. Not sure how to do this.

In JQuery, i can listen to the Column 4 cell of the last row, regardless of how many rows are added and deleted using:

```
    function addRowWithTab() {
        alert('is it listening');
        $(table).find("tr:not(.noedit):last select.selectprod").on("keydown",function(e) {
            if(e.keyCode == 9) {
              alert('tabbed !!! ');
                addRow();
            }
        });
    }
```

But how do i simulate

```
 $(table).find("tr:not(.noedit):last select.selectprod").on("keydown",function(e) {....
```

With Javascript? **So far I have the following which seems like the wrong way to even start thinking about it.**

```
    function addListener(){
        var oldlength = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName('select').length;
        var oldlength = oldlength-1;
        var el = document.getElementById("item_" + oldlength);
        el.removeEventListener("click", createRow, false);

        var length = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName('select').length;

        var el = document.getElementById("item_" + length);
        el.addEventListener("click", createRow, false);
    }
```

This is driving me nuts!   Should I try adding all the select.selectprods to a nodelist and have a function that somehow is always listening to the last one of the list, even when that list is expanding and contracting?
Please help!

Comment: Have a look at [**Document.querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) and [**Element.querySelectorAll**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll). They take  one or more CSS selectors separated by commas.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out a good workaround: It loops through all the select elements, erases the event listeners until the last select and adds the event listener. Yay.

```
    function onTab(e){
        //alert("hi" + e);
        if(e.keyCode === 9) {
            //alert('tabbed !!! ');
            createRow();
        }
    }


    function addListener(){

        var selectnodes = document.getElementById("table1").getElementsByTagName('select');
        length = selectnodes.length;

        for (i=0; i <= selectnodes.length; i++){
            if(i > 0){document.getElementById("item_" + i).removeEventListener("keydown",onTab,false);}
            if(i === selectnodes.length){
                //alert("we got here!\ni = " + i + "\nand length is " + selectnodes.length);
                document.getElementById("item_" + i).addEventListener("keydown",onTab,false);
            }
        }
    }
```